# About Oracle PURGE INDEX statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a little concern about the SQL PURGE statement of Oracle database. According to Oracle doc, we can purge index , ref [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9020.htm#SQLRF01803).

But according to Oracle Doc in Administration, index is just associated objects with table. So index can't be purged from recycle bin alone (in fact, it'll be purged when purged table).

Can someone give me an example that I can simulate "Purge index "?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you drop a table that has an index, both the table and its index will be moved to the recyclebin. At this point you can purge the index alone.

```
create table demo (id integer);

create index demo_ix on demo(id);

drop table demo;

select r.object_name, r.original_name, r.type from user_recyclebin r;

OBJECT_NAME                     ORIGINAL_NAME           TYPE
------------------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------
BIN$SC08VFzrQAGoWW5b/yBRIQ==$0  DEMO_IX                 INDEX
BIN$zIngUcYDRaqvbVqnesnUtQ==$0  DEMO                    TABLE

purge index demo_ix;

select r.object_name, r.original_name, r.type from user_recyclebin r;

OBJECT_NAME                     ORIGINAL_NAME           TYPE
------------------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------
BIN$zIngUcYDRaqvbVqnesnUtQ==$0  DEMO                    TABLE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm facing the problem with purge index only (the index implicitly created by oracle when declare primary key - unique index). I can't purge that kind of index (get ORA-00604 ORA-02429). I come to conclusion that PURGE INDEX don't apply for unique/primary index. Oracle doc just say "Specify the name of the table or index in the recycle bin that you want to purge. You can specify either the original user-specified name or the system-generated name Oracle Database ...". I thinks they should update this for saving time of reader.

Comment: Yes, *ORA-02429: cannot drop index used for enforcement of unique/primary key* is standard for indexes that support constraints. `alter table "BIN$cOzxF7g4TqeFBc9xukxTqA==$0" drop primary key;` gave *ORA-38301: can not perform DDL/DML over objects in Recycle Bin*. I guess you would have to undrop the table, drop or disable its PK and drop the table again.